# After upload on server 404 on all pages, no css

Tags: css, 404-error

I developed a WordPress based site on using XAMPP 1.8.3. On my local machine everything is working fine.

On the server I am using php 5.4.12, I copied the site files into subfolder with the same name I had in xampp/htdocs. I changed all occurrences of localhost to mydomain.com in the database with the searchreplacedb2.php script (http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases). I am confident that the tool is working properly as I have used it several other times with success.

On my local machine the site was in localhost/site, on the hosting server is on mydomain.com/site.

The problem is that accessing the site home page produces a WordPress managed 404 page with no CSS being loaded. The title, menu and other site specific text is displayed, therefore the db is being read correctly. Trying to access any page other than the home page gets a Webhost managed 404 page. This happens also if I try to access page through non symbolic urls, ei. mydomain.com/site/?page_id=5; therefore it is should not be a redirection issues.

What can be the issue? How can I proceed in troubleshooting it?

Comment: Look at the generated source of the page (ie. use your browser's "View Source") and confirm that the paths to your resources are correct.

Comment: yes  that was it.